# Why use a motor driver board?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm just getting into electronics in general and I'm confused a bit as to why I'd want/need to use a motor driver board instead of just setting up my own transistor/diode/etc when attempting to power and control a DC motor.

Any chance someone could clarify the point to using a motor driver board instead (assuming there is another option as I think there to be)?

Comment: It is for simplicity - the board will work without needing to design and build your own circuit. You _could_ design and build your own motor controller, but it would take longer. It is a bit like asking, "why buy a radio when I can make one?" :-)

Comment: @Greenonline I actually assumed a single transistor/resister/diode would be sufficient in powering a motor. I wouldn't think to build my own motor driver board knowing now more of what it is/does. That, I believe, was closer to what I should have been asking (what a motor driver board is compared to using a single transistor/diode).

Comment: It actually uses 4 transistors, to be able to reverse the motor as well. Some drivers even allow two motors in both directions. One may roll it's own, but a readymade part is usually cheaper than ging through the whole design and test/optimize iterations himself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A motor driver board is just a convenient way of creating what is known as a "H Bridge". This is an arrangement of 4 (or more, but 4 primary) transistors.

You can make it yourself with discrete transistors, but it is simpler to just use a pre-made chip.

[image]

A H Bridge gives you greater control over a motor than a single transistor alone. It allows you to control the direction, which you can't do with a single transistor, and it also gives you access to braking modes where the motor becomes harder to turn thus assisting in slowing down the load.

With a single transistor you can turn the motor on and off (or vary the speed if you use PWM) but that is all.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxRFWY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A couple of extra reasons.  If you have low power controllers (like computers), it keep the low power devices away from higher power motor drivers, electronic noise etc.

If you use AC, it can also keep the issues of driving inductive loads away from your micro-electronics (phase and power factor issues).